# upload multiple images to server at one input file in php

Tags: php, server, image-uploading, image-upload

I'm trying to upload multiple images to server at one input(click on the button), and I have following code for index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
      <form id="contact" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <!-- image 1 -->
      <label class="aa">
       Upload an image
        </label>
          <div>
           <input name="Field26"  type="file" size="12"  data-file-max-size="10"  tabindex="1"  required  />
          </div><br>
    <!-- image 2 -->
      <label class="bb">
       Upload an image
        </label>
          <div>
            <input name="Field33"  type="file" size="12"  data-file-max-size="10"  tabindex="2"  required  />
      </div>  
      </br>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload Image" data-submit="...Sending">Upload</button>

     </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have following upload.php code for uploading one image:

```
<?php
$dirCheck = 'images/$_POST[project]';
if (file_exists($dirCheck)){
    echo "Sorry, directory already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}else{
    mkdir("images/$_POST[project]",0777,true);
    echo "The new folder $_POST[project] has been created.</br>";
    $uploadOk = 1;
}

$target_dir = "images/$_POST[project]/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ". ";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

How to change the code to upload multiple images? Thanks!

Comment: Multiple files can be selected and then uploaded using the
<input type='file' name='file[]' multiple>

Answer (score 0):

you have to use an array in name attribute instead:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileupload[]" /><br><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileupload[]" /><br><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileupload[]" /><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE"/>
</form>
```

Or you can use multiple attribute:

```
<input type="file" name="fileupload[]" multiple />
```

Then in PHP you use this:

```
foreach($_FILES['fileupload'] as $file) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: can you please write the "..." part in full code? I'm new to php